# Deleting from ManyToMany with IndexColumn

Tags: java, hibernate

```
Report.entity {
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "reports_contents_relations",
             joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "report_id"),
             inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "content_id"))
  @IndexColumn(name="content_order")
private List contents = new ArrayList();
}

Someclass {
  public void remoteContentFromReport(Content content) {
    List contents = report.getContents();
    contents.remove(content);
    save(report);
  }
}
```

When calling remoteContentFromReport method I get the following error.

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException:
>   Duplicate entry deleting from
>   collection

I don't want to delete the Content.entity, just the entry in the join table associating it to a report.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just call `report.saveOrUpdate()` and it will automatically unlink all content that is not present in `report.contents` list (if everything is mapped correctly).

So get your report, remove unneeded content entries from the contents list, and save it.

Comment: I'm using spring's entity manager with jpa, so I only have merge or persist. But calling merge on the report entity, after removing my item from the collect, throws the Duplicate entry error.

Comment: I've written a very simple test app using the simplest environment and it works as I would have expected. 

I therefore think this isn't a problem with JPA/Hibernate, or the mapping, but more likely in the abstraction layer I've written in between my controllers and spring; probably something to do with transactions.